# Computing status of record based on Date Activated/Date Deactivated columns in relation to localtimestamp and other columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a design issue with one of my tables from a PostgreSQL db regarding the status of an Inventory entity.

The initial Inventory table had a couple of columns which described the supported statuses at that point (Active/Inactive/Deleted), there was no status table.

```
TABLE Inventory (
       Status - simple integer without any FKs to a dictionary table
       Date Activated Timestamp
       Date Deactivated Timestamp
)
```

While Deleted had it's standalone status value of 3, the Active/Inactive statuses had both value 0 and were computed based on the LocalTimestamp in reference to Date Activated/Date Deactivated (this was done in the Java domain class).

At one point we had to add a Suspended status which was also considered in the bucket of Active/Inactive, so the status remains 0 and the design decision at that point was to add an extra column Suspended CHAR(1) with values Y/N and create a view over the table which would now compute the Active/Inactive/Suspended based on LocalTimestamp, Date Activated, Date Deactivated, Suspended.

Now I need to add a new status for this entity, Deprecated, and I don't really want to add one more column and some more logic to that view. I would like to move to a dictionary table of the statuses and have only 1 FK between Inventory and InventoryStatus (the new table).

My issue is that now I have a properly set InventoryStatusId column, but I still need to compute the ActualInventoryStatus based on LocalTimeStamp/Date Activated/Date Deactivated (at data base level) and I am not sure how to achieve this in a performant way. I looked over PostgreSQLs generated columns, but at this point that won't work due to the fact that it only accepts immutable functions and I need LocalTimestamp in there.

I also checked ways of updating the InventoryStatusId column based on the LocalTimestamp using the pg_cron extension, using jobs, but this is not a valid solution for me because I need it to be somehow realtime computing.

I need to somehow change the design so I can easily accept new statuses in the future and also keep all the statuses that are already implemented.

Comment: Unrelated, but: "yes/no" flags should be stored as a `boolean` column, not a `char(1)` (you wouldn't use a `String` for that in Java either, would you)

Comment: I completely agree, we are forced to use CHAR columns due to some limitations of our built in ORM.

Comment: Ah the dreaded obfuscation layer. I always wonder why people accept ridiculous limitations like that in the obfuscation layer, but not in other frameworks. I am sure nobody would use Spring if it imposed stupid restrictions like that.

Comment: Would you add an algorith to produce the "final" status of a inventory? You write you have to use LocalTimeStamp - but it is not clear why is that...

Comment: Yes, we are using somehow of an algorithm, for example if an item has Date Activated = 20th Jul 2021 and Date Deactivated 27th Jul 2021, at this point (today 22nd Jul 2021) the item is considered Active because the Date Deactivated is in the future and the InventoryStatusId is for Active, but when the 28th Jul 2021 comes the Inventory needs to show as Inactive because the Date Deactivated passed, but the InventoryStatusId is still Active so we are using the 2 dates in reference to localtimestamp to decide on Active/Inactive

Comment: Because your status is dependant on current time, you can't build an index for it (status(inventory) is not immutable).  You could add a table `inventory_status` with attributes `inventory_id`, `effective_on` (ts_range) and `final_status`. Then add an index (I don't rememger gin or gist) on `inventory_id` and `interval`. The table could be maintained by trigger on `inventory` data change. To get a status you would `inventory i join inventory_status is ON i.id = is.inventory_id and current_time_stamp <@ effective_on)